# Pyodbc - Inserting values into SQL Server db error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to use python to insert values into a table.

```
TableName = "Table_Test1"
```

This is the code that I am trying:

```
cursor.execute("Insert into " + TableName + " (TestCol1,TestCol2) VALUES (?,?)", Val1, Val2)
```

What is the mistake that I am making here?

It is giving me this error - `<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'> returned a result with an error set`

Comment: Params should be inside a container -> `(Val1, Val2)`

Answer (score 0):

TestCol2 in the db was declared as nvarchar and the Val2 that the program returned was 0 which is an integer. I changed the datatype in the db and then the program started working.